# How can I easily find the most similar(or nearest) version(or commits) a source code tree is based from the open source git repo?

Tags: linux, git

My conditions are:

1. I have a source codes tar ball file, e.g. binutils-gdb.tar.gz
2. I know that it's from git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
3. But I've no ".git" directory in binutils-gdb.tar.gz, it means I don't know which version or commit the binutils-gdb.tar.gz is from

**My question: How can I know which version or commit in git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git generating my current binutils-gdb.tar.gz?**

I know that if I check the files in binutils-gdb.tar.gz one by one, e.g. the version file, it's possible I could get the correct version or commits for the binutils.tar.gz in git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
But this kind of manual checking work is too tedious, do we have some tools/scripts to do this work?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+similar+commit

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. extract the all the files in `tar.gz`
2. clone git repo
3. compare both trees
4. if all files are equal `HEAD` is the commit in the `tar.gz`
5. else checkout `HEAD~1`
6. go to compare

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If HEAD~1 is not same as my source tree, then HEAD~2? Then HEAD~3?  This is too tedious, any other more powerfull tools or solution to this ?

Comment: You can easily create a script to do it